Schematic Page idn't being refreshed
I'm trying to define some scripts for Altium Designer using DelphiScript.
In this one i'm making a param updater and i have 2 "problems".
Since i'm able to update/create params and its text, after that i don't know how to refresh the schematic view. Let me explain.
Imagine i create a Param named "Checked" with value "designer" with the script but then, if i don't save (Ctrl+S) the schematic or refresh the params tab you can't see them created/updated.
The other problem is that until i don't make another change in the schematic page or i open it again, the changes aren't applied to the TextStrings in the page which have assigned the value of params.
I've trying a lot of things in the poor Altium API documentation and i'm not able to do it.
My code is the following.
unit Form1Unit;

interface

uses
  Forms, StdCtrls, Dialogs, SysUtils, Classes, SchLib, SchServer;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    CheckBox2: TCheckBox;
    CheckBox3: TCheckBox;
    CheckBox4: TCheckBox;
    CheckBox5: TCheckBox;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure UpdateParameter(const ParamName, ParamValue: string);
    procedure LoadParametersIntoComboBox();
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Inicializar la interfaz
  LoadParametersIntoComboBox();
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Text := DateToStr(Now);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit4.Text := DateToStr(Now);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked then
    UpdateParameter('CheckedBy', Edit1.Text);
  if CheckBox2.Checked then
    UpdateParameter('CheckedDate', Edit2.Text);
  if CheckBox3.Checked then
    UpdateParameter('ApprovedBy', Edit3.Text);
  if CheckBox4.Checked then
    UpdateParameter('ApprovedDate', Edit4.Text);
  if CheckBox5.Checked then
    UpdateParameter(ComboBox1.Text, Edit5.Text);

  // Refrescar el documento esquemático
  RunProcess('WorkspaceManager:Save');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
          begin // Llamar a RefreshSchematicView cuando se cierre el formulario
                //RefreshSchematicView;
                SchDoc.GraphicallyInvalidate;
                ResetParameters;
                AddStringParameter('Action', 'Document');
                RunProcess('Sch:Zoom');

          end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateParameter(const ParamName, ParamValue: string);
var
  SchServerInterface: ISch_ServerInterface;
  Project: IProject;
  Doc: IDocument;
  SchDoc: ISch_Document;
  SchematicPath: String;
  i: Integer;
  Iterator: ISch_Iterator;
  Param: ISch_Parameter;
begin
  // Obtener la interfaz del SchServer
  SchServerInterface := SchServer;
  if SchServerInterface = nil then
  begin
    ShowMessage('No se pudo obtener la interfaz del SchServer.');
    Exit;
  end;

  // Obtener el proyecto actual
  Project := GetWorkspace.DM_FocusedProject;
  if Project = nil then
  begin
    ShowMessage('No hay ningún proyecto abierto.');
    Exit;
  end;

  // Encontrar el esquemático en el proyecto
  SchematicPath := '';
  for i := 0 to Project.DM_LogicalDocumentCount - 1 do
  begin
    Doc := Project.DM_LogicalDocuments(i);
    if SameText(Doc.DM_DocumentKind, 'SCH') then
    begin
      SchematicPath := Doc.DM_FullPath;
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  if SchematicPath = '' then
  begin
    ShowMessage('No se encontró ningún esquemático en el proyecto.');
    Exit;
  end;

  // Abrir el documento esquemático utilizando RunProcess
  RunProcess('Sch:Open|' + 'DocumentPath=' + SchematicPath);

  // Obtener el documento esquemático actual
  SchDoc := SchServerInterface.GetCurrentSchDocument;
  if SchDoc = nil then
  begin
    ShowMessage('No se pudo abrir el esquemático.');
    Exit;
  end;

  // Borrar cualquier parámetro existente con el mismo nombre
  Iterator := SchDoc.SchIterator_Create;
  Iterator.AddFilter_ObjectSet(MkSet(eParameter));
  try
    Param := Iterator.FirstSchObject;
    while Param <> nil do
    begin
      if SameText(Param.Name, ParamName) then
      begin
        SchDoc.RemoveSchObject(Param);
      end;
      Param := Iterator.NextSchObject;
    end;
  finally
    SchDoc.SchIterator_Destroy(Iterator);
  end;

  // Crear y añadir el nuevo parámetro
  Param := SchServerInterface.SchObjectFactory(eParameter, eCreate_Default);
  Param.Name := ParamName;
  Param.Text := ParamValue;
  SchDoc.AddSchObject(Param);

  // Recargar parámetros en el ComboBox
  LoadParametersIntoComboBox();
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadParametersIntoComboBox();
var
  SchServerInterface: ISch_ServerInterface;
  Project: IProject;
  Doc: IDocument;
  SchDoc: ISch_Document;
  Iterator: ISch_Iterator;
  Param: ISch_Parameter;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Limpiar el ComboBox
  ComboBox1.Items.Clear;

  // Obtener la interfaz del SchServer
  SchServerInterface := SchServer;
  if SchServerInterface = nil then
  begin
    ShowMessage('No se pudo obtener la interfaz del SchServer.');
    Exit;
  end;

  // Obtener el proyecto actual
  Project := GetWorkspace.DM_FocusedProject;
  if Project = nil then
  begin
    ShowMessage('No hay ningún proyecto abierto.');
    Exit;
  end;

  // Iterar sobre los documentos lógicos del proyecto
  for i := 0 to Project.DM_LogicalDocumentCount - 1 do
  begin
    Doc := Project.DM_LogicalDocuments[i];
    if SameText(Doc.DM_DocumentKind, 'SCH') then
    begin
      // Abrir el documento esquemático utilizando RunProcess
      RunProcess('Sch:Open|' + 'DocumentPath=' + Doc.DM_FullPath);

      // Obtener el documento esquemático actual
      SchDoc := SchServerInterface.GetCurrentSchDocument;
      if SchDoc = nil then
      begin
        ShowMessage('No se pudo abrir el esquemático.');
        Continue;
      end;

      // Iterar sobre los parámetros del documento esquemático
      Iterator := SchDoc.SchIterator_Create;
      Iterator.AddFilter_ObjectSet(MkSet(eParameter));
      try
        Param := Iterator.FirstSchObject;
        while Param <> nil do
        begin
          ComboBox1.Items.Add(Param.Name);
          Param := Iterator.NextSchObject;
        end;
        SchDoc.GraphicallyInvalidate;
        ResetParameters;
        AddStringParameter('Action', 'Document');
        RunProcess('Sch:Zoom');
        Client.SendMessage('SCH:Zoom', 'Action=Document' , 255, Client.CurrentView);
      finally
        SchDoc.SchIterator_Destroy(Iterator);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
end.

In the final lines i'm using different Methods all together because was my last trial to see if anyone worked...
Basically i tried to update parameters and see the changes done in the schematic only with the script button clicked but graphically they aren't updated in schematic neither in params tab.
